# Overheat , fan undetected

Tags: release-freya

My fans don't work on my laptop clevo N150SD and when I make sensors I get this

[image]

I already do `sensors-detect`.

Any idea how i can get work my fans ?

Comment: you know that running at 50 degrees  is nothing, it is almost the idle temperature. cpu's on linux can make 90 degrees. on my laptop on idle it is 45 degrees.  when doing something it is almost every time at 60-70 degrees. why?  because the linux kernel developers think if you get the task done quicker you save energy because the cpu is more time in idle state. this resolutes in what users call overheating. Well in fact it isn't overheating it is just doing it's job.